# Do child threads inherit the parent's ThreadScope in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java, I have a `Thread` `A`. If `A` spawns a child thread, `b`, does `b` have access to any/all `ThreadLocal` variables that were set by `A`?

Comment: **ThreadScope**? There is no such thing in Java. Do you mean **ThreadLocals**? If this is what you mean, no, they don't have access to other thread's thread local variables.

Comment: yes `ThreadLocal` is the object, sorry about that. `ThreadLocal` creates thread-scopred variables, whence my confusion.

Comment: What does the term "child" mean in this context? What is a "child thread"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean InheritableThreadLocal (extending ThreadLocal), then yes, each child thread will have the initial default value to be the same as the parent thread value. But any changes by the child thread will be local to the child.

[InheritableThreadLocal doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InheritableThreadLocal.html)

Comment: Any changes by the child thread. Will reflect in parent thread.  childvalue method had to be override to have different behaviour

Comment: The reference to the object will be local to the child. If the child stores another object in the ThreadLocal, then this will not be reflected in the parent. However, if the child modifies the object which the ThreadLocal references, then that will be reflected in the parent. Basically, the child gets a copy of map of thread locals, but the map references the same values as the parent.

Comment: Yes. Bottom line, if we set BigInterger value as 1 in parent Threadlocal , while we use inheritableThreadLocal , we will get as 1 in child thread initially . but if we change value to 5 in any one of the child thread, then the Parent Thread and all child's thread of this parent will get 5 . So it has to be use carefully. we can change this behaviour by cloning the instance before return value in childValue method

Comment: Warning: InheritableThreadLocal does NOT work with thread pools. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012371/using-inheritablethreadlocal-with-threadpoolexecutor-or-a-threadpoolexecut

Answer (score 4):

No, each thread has their own stack.  When you create a Thread from another thread they are given a new Thread Stack that is completely different from the creating thread.