# How to measure request time in distributed system?

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, distributed

After my research I decided to log from each component for every request: time, localization and some kind of request-ID. Then take it all together and sort by ID. Then I can have information how long does it take to go through single component for each request, what is exactly what I need.

My problem is I don't know how to pass ID across the system (threads are created e.g. by RMI). My idea was to set the same thread name to all threads connected to one request ([see discusion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722749/how-to-find-the-name-of-the-parent-thread)), but I still need some advice how to do this. Or maybe there is better idea to gather threads together?

Comment: Can you provide some more backgroup @trebuchet?  What components?  What sort of system is this?  Why are you doing this?  The 2nd paragraph is confusing and should probably be deleted.  Just explain _clearly_ what you are trying to accomplish _without_ providing a solution.  Thread-ids are _not_ the way to go.

Comment: What do you pass to new threads created by RMI? What input?

Comment: any thread local information is only going to be available within a single jvm, so this won't help much for a distributed system (unless you only care about tracking the client side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have done this is to pass a String containing a timestamp of all the key steps in the process.  At the end I have a complete end-to-end record of all the timing. This means passing an extra argument, but since the reporting is much simpler it can be worth it.