# How to get Thread name from parent?

Tags: java, multithreading

How to set **the same name** for parent and child in this situation?

```
public class ComponentA {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Bye bye = new Bye();
        Thread t = new Thread(bye);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

I cannot add `t.setName(Thread.currentThread().getName());`, because I need to avoid changing code. I'm looking for solution I can apply from AspectJ class.
Is there any way to put an argument to `run` method? Or maybe in child thread we can get `parent name`?

**EDIT:**

I mean:

- parent - main in ComponentA
- child - run in Bye

Comment: What do you mean by "parent" and "child"? Are you referring to `Bye` (which must be in the inheritance tree that includes `Runnable`) as the child and the `Thread` object `t` as the parent?

Comment: What is parent? What is name? Do you want to get the main thread's name from the started thread (`t`)?

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722749/how-to-find-the-name-of-the-parent-thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

> Is there any way to put an argument to run method? Or maybe in child thread we can get parent name?

Once the thread has started and the `run()` method has been called, there is no way to find out the name of the parent thread as was discussed in this answer here:

> [How to find the name of the parent thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722749/how-to-find-the-name-of-the-parent-thread/11722898#11722898)

You can certainly do:

```
Bye bye = new Bye();
Thread t = new Thread(bye, Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-child");
t.start();
```

This sets the name of the newly created thread to be related to the current thread which is it's parent.  But with the edit you made, I see that you can't change how the thread has been forked.

As was mentioned in my other answer, I think you are going to have to use some other mechanism aside from the name to group your threads.

Inside of the `run()` method, you can certainly make a call to add the current thread into some collection of threads for reporting purposes.

Comment: +1 You can change the name Java thinks the thread is (appears in thread dumps)

Comment: Thanks a lot, adding one argument to constructor is enough for me. I've done some research about BCEL. It can add extra argument to method in its byte code.

Comment: Wow!  You are serious about the name change for sure @trebuchet!

Answer (score -1):

By using `Thread.setName()`.

[Read More here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Comment: Sorry , its my mistake. its setName