# how to find out who create a thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

in tomcat,if a webapp did stop a none daemon thread,tomcat can not be shutdown by shutdown.sh

for example:

```
public class demo implements ServletContextListener{

  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // yes,we can cancel timer in here,but this is not the major problem
   }

  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {        
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new Test(), 1000, 1000*10);
    }
}

public class Test extends TimerTask{  
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("AAAA");        
   }
}
```

like as above,tomcat can not be shutdown by shutdown.sh.
from jvisualvm,threads inspector say:

```
"Timer-0" - Thread t@40
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <3957edeb> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

stack info did not point out which java class created the thread,
my question is how to find out who created the thread from many webapps.

Thanks!

Comment: easiest way would be to start each webapp individually and check threads.

Comment: thanks,it is good way in test environment,but how to do in online?

Comment: More discussion in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722749/how-to-find-the-name-of-the-parent-thread

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is the list of approaches, sorted from quickest / most reliable to slowest / hardest:

1. If you have the source of the class, create an exception in the constructor (without actually throwing it). You can simply examine or print it when you need to know when the thread was created.
2. If you don't have the sources, the thread name can be a good hint who created it.
3. If the name hints to a generic service (like `java.util.Timer`), then you can create a conditional breakpoint in your IDE in the constructor. The condition should be the thread name; the debugger will then stop when someone creates a thread with this name.
4. If you don't have too many threads, set a breakpoint in the constructors of `Thread`.
5. If you have many threads, attach a debugger to the app and freeze it. Then examine the stack traces.
6. If everything else fails, get the [source code for the Java runtime](http://openjdk.java.net/) and add logging code in the classes you want to observe, compile a new `rt.jar` and replace the original one with your version. Don't try this in production, please.
7. If money isn't an issue, you can use dynamic tracing tools like [Compuware APM](http://www.compuware.com/en_us/application-performance-management/products/application-monitoring.html) or, if you're on Linux or Solaris, you can try [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/) and dtrace, respectively.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Digulla very much  
so good and detail.  
in this case,we can only get stack info just like above

so i tried to use btrace for get more detail,unfortunate i got nothing helpful info yet.  
anyway,thanks Aaron Digulla,your reply contains a lot of useful information.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron Digulla . your 4th and 5th point saved me a week effort. Attached debug points to Thread Constructor and debugged to find out who created the thread which was causing issue in my application.

Answer (score 3):

You can also write a tiny java Instrumentation agent to wrap the thread constructor (and stack dump there), instead of trying to mod the rt.jar classes.

Comment: You'd think by now someone would already have an agent implementation to decorate thread names with file name & line number…‍

Comment: Apparently, there is Byteman https://stackoverflow.com/a/68613191/673826

Comment: If I had to do this again, I'd probably be disappointed by the sheer number of thread pools everywhere for nearly no reason but to appear smart in a design that doesn't need it. Every so called senior (with only 5 years or experience...) throws in their own pooled executor services with 10 threads without justifying it. I started controlling threads in 1998, and I practically stopped in 2015 because I'm overwhelmed by awful architectures and 3rd party libraries that can't even handle an interrupt correctly. Sad, sad state of concurrent programming.

Answer (score 2):

If you have control of the class you can catch the stack trace when it is created:

```
public class Test extends TimerTask {
  final StackTraceElement[] callerStack;

  public Test () {
    callerStack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("AAAA");
    System.out.println("Creator: "+Arrays.asList(callerStack));
  }

  @Override
  public String toString () {
    return "Test created by "+Arrays.asList(callerStack);
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry,in some case,we can not control source,and we even did not which thread or class lead to tomcat shutdown fail.

so,my question is how to find out the thread or class,so that we can notify the code owner.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an IDE like Eclipse or Intellij, you can set break points in the various Thread constructors.  You can remotely attach to process using the debugger.  The debugger will stop the process when the thread is being constructed.  You can observe things like the thread name.  You can also use break points with condition if you want to match on the specific thread name.

Setting break points.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/

Remote debugging 
https://dzone.com/articles/a-practical-guide-to-java-remote-debugging-in-the

Answer (score 0):

One may use [Byteman](https://byteman.jboss.org/) to locate where a thread was started from.

Here is a Windows-based snippet to get an idea. It is imperative to use `boot` option for Byteman as well as setting `org.jboss.byteman.transform.all`.

```
set BYTEMAN_HOME=C:\tools\byteman-download-4.0.22
set BYTEMAN=%BYTEMAN_HOME%\lib\byteman.jar
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-javaagent:%BYTEMAN%=script:appmain.btm,boot:%BYTEMAN%"
java -Dorg.jboss.byteman.transform.all -jar whatever...
```

Create `appmain.btm` with something like

```
RULE trace thread start
CLASS java.lang.Thread
METHOD start
IF true
DO traceStack("*** found the caller for " + $0.getName() + "\n", 10)
ENDRULE
```

Once you run your application, you should be able to see something like

```
*** found the caller for pool-3-thread-1
java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:-1)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1367)
java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
...
```

There should be a user code somewhere further down the stack.