# Android - How can I find out where the current thread was created?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading

I'm working on a huge Android app using Eclipse that's got tons of code the I'm unfamiliar with.

There's a thread that's being spawned way too many times, and I'm not sure where it's being spawned as there's lots of code that spawns this thread.

**How can I find where the thread was spawned in Eclipse?**

Note: The thread does appear to have a name of sorts... In the thread Debug stacktrace, I can see "Thread  [<18> ***] where *** is some dynamic info (not a simple string that's embedded in the app).

Comment: There's no clear cut way to know where a thread came from. You can however try a few approaches :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999444/how-to-find-out-who-create-a-thread-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Aneesh said, this is answered here on StackOverflow. You asked about Android, but it's the same for Java pretty much:

[how to find out who create a thread in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999444/how-to-find-out-who-create-a-thread-in-java)