# Shutdown ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor opened by 3rd party JAR during JVM stop

Tags: mongodb, threadpool, permgen

During JVM stop, few of the `thread pool` are not getting closed properly. Due to this `Perm Gen leak` happens as class loader is restricted from being Garbage collected.

These thread pool are opened by 3rd party application (Elasticsearch) and I do not have any direct control over it other than `client` instance.

`client` instance do provide methods for `shutting down` the `scheduler` and `thread pool` but this error is not getting rectified. '

Please help. Is there any way we can get instance of `3rd Parties` `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and shutdown it through Java application?

Comment: actually it was Mongo client which created this thread and not elasticsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer solved by referring these two articles:

Plumbr tool helped in providing the class loader leak reference and details of thread causing the memory leak.

**Article 1:**
This article suggested how to find out who created the Thread which is causing the memory leak.

[how to find out who create a thread in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999444/how-to-find-out-who-create-a-thread-in-java/18999877#18999877)

Answer by @Aaron Digulla saved me. Especially 4th and 5th point.

**Article 2:**
This article suggested how to close the client.

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/nosql/118557-mongo-application-fails-to-stop-thread-mongocleaner-with-redeploy-or-restart-tomcat