# Is it possible to hook thread creation?

Tags: java, hook

I am making a plugin system and i need to see when a plugin calls Thread.start()
Is there a way similar to Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook but for hooking when a thread starts?

Comment: Thread factory.

Comment: I'm afraid it's a more generic question here. TFs make sense if they are used, but we'd want to capture _any_ `Thread.start()` event - no matter where the thread is coming from. Something like having a breakpoint in IDE on that method.

Comment: I found another cool method. Apparently it's possible to redefine classes before they are loaded by the JVM by using a Java Agent. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html . I'll add this as an answer if I ever figure out a code sample.

Comment: Hey, to whom ever it interests, I did find a library that can create a Java Agent to modify a class during runtime. I updated my answer with an example. Cheers! Hibernate actually uses ByteBuddy to create Entity proxies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Byteman

You can use [Byteman](https://byteman.jboss.org/) to inject your own code into the thread.start() method.

In fact, the first example to using Byteman with JVM classes on their website is one showing how to print to the console when a thread has started.

Byteman script example from their tutorial:

```
RULE trace thread start

CLASS java.lang.Thread

METHOD start()

IF true

DO traceln("*** start for thread: "+ $0.getName())

ENDRULE
```

See https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-17213#how_do_i_inject_code_into_jvm_classes for further implementation details.

---

## ByteBuddy

If Byteman isn't your thing, there's another library called [ByteBuddy](https://bytebuddy.net/) which can be used to create a [Java Agent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) that intercepts a method in the Thread class.

```
public class ThreadMonitor {
  @RuntimeType
  public static Object intercept(@Origin Method method, 
                                 @SuperCall Callable<?> callable) {
    System.out.println("A thread start method called");
      return callable.call(); //Calling the original start method.
  }
}

public class ThreadMonitorAgent {
  public static void premain(String arguments, 
                             Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
      .type(ElementMatchers.nameEndsWith("start"))
      .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) -> 
          builder.method(ElementMatchers.any())
                 .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(ThreadMonitor.class))
      ).installOn(instrumentation);
  }
}
```

*Example code adapted from ByteBuddy github [readme](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy#changing-existing-classes).*

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate threads but there is no way to hook on creation synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.  Maybe there is a way.

If there is a `SecurityManager` for the current context, then there is a check to see if the current thread is permitted to access the `ThreadGroup` of the new `Thread` when it is being constructed.

So ...

You could (in theory) set up a custom `SecurityManager` and use the thread group access check as a way to "hook" the creation of a new `Thread`.  But this will only tell you that a thread is being created, not what that thread actually it.  So this approach may or may not be sufficient for your needs.

And there is no way to hook the `Thread.start()` call.

---

An alternative approach would be to extend `Thread` and implement the hooks on thread creation or starting in your subclass.

You could attach a debugger to your JVM and set a breakpoint to `Thread.start()`.  Or even do it programmatically using JVMTI, etc.  **However**, it is (AFAIK) not possible for an application to use JVMTI against its own JVM<sup>1</sup> ... so this is not conventional "hooking".

Finally, there is always the option of downloading OpenJDK, modifying the `Thread` class, building a custom JVM, and installing it.  That might be OK for doing some experiments, but it would be a crazy thing to do for a production application.  (You don't want to burden yourself ... or your customers ... with maintaining a perpetual fork of OpenJDK.)

---

<sup>1 - Even if it was possible in some cases, the `Thread` class would present extra difficulties.  For example, consider that things like bytecode rewriting have to be done before the classloader loads a class.  But the `Thread` class has to be loaded during JVM bootstrapping ... and before any application code has been loaded.</sup>

Comment: AFAICT you wouldn't need to build a whole custom JVM, replacement of `Thread.class` in standard-library's jar _should_ be enough (unless signatures are involved!)

Comment: You are still maintaining a fork of the standard system library.   Each time you update the JVM you have to re-apply your changes. (And from Java 9+ onwards, it is not in a JAR file ...)  There is also the issue that there are some *gnarly* relationships between the JVM native code, the Java SE libraries, JVM bootstrapping and things like remote debug tools.

Answer (score 0):

Not in normal fashion, but remember that `Thread.start` is public and non-final, so you could create a subclass of Thread that would do your custom logic before start. *But that's obviously not good enough for this question.*

The black-magic solution that might work would be to remove the existing `Thread` class from runtime (what means modifying your JRE/JDK) and replacing it with your "enriched" version. As long as the new version does the same thing as "normal" one (registering natives, invoking native code) then it should be fine.

Another black-magic alternative would be to actually take a look into what's the native code that's invoked by `Thread.start0` and modify that. But this means playing with your runtime environment again.

Final idea would be to have the application always run in something similar to a debug mode and do something whenever breakpoint is reached. This is doable, as it's what IDEs do. Though we have just moved to two-process design with what it entails.

I'm also wondering if [Java instrumentation package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) might not provide some kind of alternative here.

Comment: Debugging and instrumentation both involve an agent and an external application.  AFAIK, a JVM cannot debug or instrument itself.

Comment: Technically I've done this before, Replaced a class file in a library with one I compiled myself to fix a bug. It's a hidden gem of Java.