# Is java method Thread.setDaemon(true) the equivalent in C# to Thread.IsBackground = true?

Tags: java, c#, multithreading

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2213340/111110) and some documentation, and I would want to know if these two codes are equivalent:

in Java SE8:

```
 Thread th1 = new Thread(() -> { doStuff(); });    
 th1.setDaemon(true);
 th1.start();
```

In C#:

```
 Thread th1 = new Thread(doStuff);
 th1.IsBackground = true;
 th1.Start();
```

I've read the MSDN documentation, but I wanted to know it they are equivalent from the framework point of view (garbage collection, finalizers, memory management, etc).
In both cases: th1 dies in the same way after its parent thread "dies"?

MSDN mentions "a process", but Oracle mentions "the JVM itself". This is what confuses me.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Nambari: Yes, I've read a lot of that, I think I'll need to edit my question

Comment: JVM itself is a process. Every programming language uses its own terminology and its own architecture, don't compare word to word.

Comment: "...after its parent thread "dies"?..."  I don't know about .NET, but in Java, there is no parent/child relationship between threads.  If thread P created thread C, that may mean something to your application, but it means nothing to the JVM.

Comment: @james large: oops, as Nambari said: it is all in the jargon. In .Net, it is common to say Thread P would be the "Parent" and Thread C would be "the child". I found this interesting info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722749/how-to-find-the-name-of-the-parent-thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent. [From the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread.
>   Background threads are identical to foreground threads, **except that
>   background threads do not prevent a process from terminating.** Once all
>   foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common
>   language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads
>   are stopped and do not complete.